# How to prevent pixel flood attack on Node.js (with Express and Multer)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, multer

I am using the multer module to help with images being posted to an Express endpoint. I am aware of the pixel flood attack, see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1513, and I wanted to know, how can I prevent such attack with my setup?

Comment: Are you processing those images in your server? If so, what are you using to process them? If not, I don't think this attack will be an issue (as Express and multer don't parse image files).

Comment: @robertklep is correct, if you aren't resizing the images on your server you'll be fine.

Comment: @Grant I'm not resizing, Im just uploading them to s3, but other people will have access to these s3 links

Comment: @DanielKobe The main thing seems to be avoiding using EXIF data for picture orientation -- if you look under the hood in Multer, is it using EXIF for anything? Might be a good one to ask on their issues page